# automatically add date to excel form after input

Tags: excel, vba, forms, date

In my excel code I want to add the date after information is entered into the form. I don't want to manually enter the date. It should just go in automatically once and should not be updated unless manually.

[image]

Comment: Use the `Change`-Event of the sheet

Comment: It's not clear what date you need. In your vba code you can use Date() function to get the current date

Comment: @Vasya i can use it to get the current date but I dont want it to change every time I open the excel sheet on a new date.

Comment: @FunThomas never heard of that could you explain more?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text to the most recently used date every time textbox is opened (or whatever trigger works best for you) like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.TextBox1.Value = Sheet1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value
End Sub
```

And it comes out looking like this:
[image: User Form Example]

> ::

Additional References/Images:

```
Sub Rectangle1_Click()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

[image: Layout Example]

Comment: Its saying invalid use of me keyboard